# source formatting pass through to the Google Sheets dropdown feature?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, dropdown

In Google Sheets, I have a list of sentences on one tab and have created a dropdown that uses the list on another tab. On the list tab I've bolded certain words the sentences. However, the dropdown and selected dropdown item displays the sentences as plain text.

Conditional formatting will not help me.

Example Formatted list:
The **quick** brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox **jumped** over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy **dog**.

Resulting dropdown options:
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

Comment: Data Validation dropdowns wont help you here, they store only values, not values and associated additional properties (like formatting) of values.

Comment: Any workaround to this problem?